# To add one day to minDate (using datapicker)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a code here on how to add one day to the minDate. I've tried multiple suggested solutions here in Stackoverflow, it came out with no success result.

Here is my code (after tried various way to solve)

```
$('#cal_mulamhn').datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      beforeShow: function() {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#cal_tmtmhn').val());
      }
    });
    $('#cal_tmtmhn').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      beforeShow: function(selectedDate) {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', addDays(new Date(selectedDate), 1));
        if ($('#cal_mulamhn').val() === '') $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', 0);
      }
    });
```

Anybody can help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet have two date pickers, from-date and to-date. In this example,

- from-date's `maxDate` is updated based on the selected to-date
- to-date's `minDate` is updated based on the selected from-date
- on selecting from-date, sets the next day as to-date in case to-date is not already selected

```js
$(function () {
    $('#cal_mulamhn').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShow: function (input, instance) {
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#cal_tmtmhn').val());
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, instance) {
            if (dateText) {
                var $cal_tmtmhn = $('#cal_tmtmhn'), dt_cal_mulamhn = $cal_tmtmhn.data('datepicker'),
                    $this = $(this), dt_this = $this.data('datepicker');
                if (dt_cal_mulamhn.input.val().trim() == "") {
                    var nextDate = new Date(+dt_this.selectedYear, +dt_this.selectedMonth, +dt_this.selectedDay + 1);
                    $cal_tmtmhn.datepicker('setDate', nextDate);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $('#cal_tmtmhn').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        beforeShow: function (input, instance) {
            var $cal_mulamhn = $('#cal_mulamhn'), $this = $(this);
            var minDate = $cal_mulamhn.val() || 0;
            if (minDate != 0) {
                var dt_cal_mulamhn = $cal_mulamhn.data('datepicker');
                // Generally to date can be same as from date
                minDate = new Date(+dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedYear, +dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedMonth, +dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedDay);
                // If needed to add 1 day to minDate use below code
                // minDate = new Date(+dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedYear, +dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedMonth, +dt_cal_mulamhn.selectedDay + 1);
            }
            $this.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<p>
    From: <input id="cal_mulamhn"/>
</p>
<p>
    To: <input id="cal_tmtmhn"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Wazeed. But I want to do like this for example : I've choosed 21/4/2020 for from-date, and I wanna do it default at the to-date, so it will become 22/4/2020 on the calender.

Comment: @WulanYaya, I have updated the answer to set default value in to-date using the [onClose event](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) at from-date. Please check it out, hope this helps.

Comment: I see and understand already how it works. And it also works fine in my code. That is the answer that I searched for. Thank you so much for your help ! :))